Mysterious evaluation inside DiscretePlot
I'm trying to solve a mystery, I made the following code:
n = 5;
h = 10000;

r := RandomInteger[{1, h}]
s := RandomInteger[{-h, h}]

Do[a[i] = s, {i, 0, 2 n}]; 

X = Table[x^i, {i, 0, 2 n}] . Table[a[i], {i, 0, 2 n}];         
P[y_] := X /. x -> y;         
a[2 n + 1] = r;
Q[x_] := (P[x] + a[2 n + 1] x^(2 n + 1));

DiscretePlot[(Q[1]), {x, -10, 10}]

Q[1] is supposed to be the polynomial Q evaluated at x=1. If you run Q[1] several times, it will yield a constant. But the plot above gives several different values.
I noticed that if I run:
Table[(Q[1]), {u, 10}]
Table[(Q[1]), {x, 10}]

The first table gives constant values while the second gives different values. Why does this happen?

Look at Trace[Table[(Q[1]), {x, 10}]] to see what's going on

Look at the documentation for DiscretePlot. You will find a sentence:

DiscretePlot treats the variable n as local, effectively using Block.

Therefore, using DiscretePlot at various n is equivalent to, for example:
Block[{x = 0}, Q[1]]
(* 7424 *)
Block[{x = 1}, Q[1]]
(* -8952 *)
Block[{x = 2}, Q[1]]
(* -7747434 *)

Namely, instead of replacement x -> y happening in P, the replacement will be 0 -> y (or 1 -> y ...).
You can either use Evaluate, or define Q with Set instead of SetDelayed:
DiscretePlot[Evaluate[Q[1]], {x, -20, 20}]

(* or *)

Clear[Q];
Q[x_] = (P[x] + a[2  n + 1]  x^(2  n + 1));
DiscretePlot[Q[1], {x, -20, 20}]


